# PHP valor inteiro sendo modificado sem motivo aparente

Tags: php, inteiros

Pessoal estou tendo problemas com a alteração de um numero inteiro que começa com zero.

```
$agencia = 0736;
$conta = 999999;

$agencia = intval($agencia); 
$conta = intval($conta); 
echo($agencia); //resultado 478
```

Mesmo sem o intval estava dando o mesmo problema. Porém seu colocar no lugar do zero o número 1 por exemplo. Irá imprimir corretamente(1736).
::PHP versão 7.0::

Comment: por que não trata ele como string? acredito que ira resolver seu problema!

Comment: Já tentei, mas como eu passo a informação para uma classe, quando eu resgato já está alterado o valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lodi obrigado pela ajuda, nos comentários do manual encontrei essa "solução".

```
$agencia = "0736" + 0;
```

Dessa forma é cancelado o octa decimal e passa o valor sem o zero: 736;
Mas aí é só pegar e colocar de novo com a função:

```
str_pad($agencia, 4 , '0' , STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Que completa a quantidades de caracteres a esquerda com zero.

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o `sprintf`

```
sprintf('%08d', 1234567);
```

**output:**
012345678

o 8d é a quantidade de dígitos que você quer

Answer (score 1):

Números iniciados com zero, desde que válidos, são interpretados com base 8 (octal), ou seja, 02345674 foi interpretado com base 8 e sua representação em base 10 é `641980.`

O manual alerta sobre isso na página sobre [integers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Esse [site](http://www.statman.info/conversions/octal.html) faz conversões entre base 8 X base 10

se você fizer assim acredito que dara certo `(int)$agencia;`

Comment: Não funcionou porque esse valor eu envio para uma classe, e dentro da classe já chega convertido também. Por sorte, lá no manual do link que passou, tem um comentário de 5 anos atrás de um cara com o mesmo problema. E a solução é ridícula para uma linguagem robusta como o PHP.

Comment: coloca aqui a solução para ajudar a galera então! quiser editar minha resposta ou criar outra fica a vontade!

Comment: Coloquei como resposta. Valeu!